# Android: Remove activity back Arrow

Tags: android, android-activity

I created two blank activities in android studio and it looks like it adds back arrow by default. My `MainActivity` is parent of`ResultActivity`. I want to maintain this hierarchy but want to get rid of back arrow.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're on API level 14 or above and are not using ActionbarSherlock, this code in `onCreateOptionsMenu` should disable the up button;

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);      // Disable the button
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // Remove the left caret
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // Remove the icon
}
```

If you're using a support lib such as ActionbarSherlock, then use;

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);      // Disable the button
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // Remove the left caret
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // Remove the icon
```

Comment: I tried adding it in ResultActivity after setContentView but I am getting getActionBar(); as null. So, it throws NullPointerException. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In onCreateOptionsMenu too I get actionBar as null, so if{} is not executed. So arrow is still seen.

Comment: Should I use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar() method?

Comment: Yes, if you're using a support lib then use `getSupportActionBar()`

Answer (score 3):

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I tried adding it in ResultActivity after setContentView but I am getting getActionBar(); as null. So, it throws NullPointerException. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using support lib? Then geSupportActionBar is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I came across this now and had to take some additional action to remove the back arrow.

So in addition to this piece of code as indicated the correct answer

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

you will also need to remove the parent-child relationship in the AndroidManifest.xml file . Your activity should not have the following entry

```
android:parentActivityName
```

Might help someone else who stumbles across this one.